# Scanning local docker image for vulnerability using Trivy gives unauthorized

Tags: docker, docker-registry, trivy

I've pulled a docker image from a private repository to local and trying to scan the local image with trivy image command. It is pulling the database but showing Unauthorized error to access the local image

```
scan error: unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize a docker scanner: 3 errors occurred:
        * unable to inspect the image (index.docker.io/library/58625f3e2b28:latest): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
        * unable to initialize Podman client: no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no such file or directory
        * GET https://index.docker.io/v2/library/58625f3e2b28/manifests/latest: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:library/58625f3e2b28 Type:repository]]
```

Docker deamon is running and the image is also in local.
Trivy version: 0.22.0
I'm running Trivy as a docker container and using below command to scan the local image

```
docker run aquasec/trivy image <<imagename>>
```

Comment: maybe because it's a private image it has no data on it? also from user and type of machine\OS are you running this?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli it has data.. i've pulled that to local using my credentials. And I tried scanning it in WSL2 ubuntu and windows powershell, git bash. All were giving same error

Comment: how did you install `trivy` and how did you run the scanning command? also, maybe it's a permissions thing, try running cmd as admin and run `docker ps` to make sure the daemon is running (I know you've checked that, I'm making sure anyway by running a command that needs to talk to the daemon)

Comment: @NoamYizraeli actually I'm running trivy as a docker container.. it is pulling CVE results to its database and then throwing this error. I'm running this inside a wsl2 ubuntu with sudo access. It is showing the type as registry in the error msg even though i'm trying to run a image in my local

Comment: command used to scan is `docker run aquasec/trivy image <<imagename>>`

Answer (score 10):

The official [documentation](https://aquasecurity.github.io/trivy/v0.28.0/getting-started/installation/#docker) states that you have to mount the Docker socket if you wish to scan an image on your host machine.

The command would then look like this:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock aquasec/trivy image <<imagename>>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had `"userns-remap": "default"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, so I just had to add `--userns=host` to Trivy:

```
docker run \
    --userns=host \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /opt/trivy_cache:/tmp/trivy \
    aquasec/trivy \
    --cache-dir /tmp/trivy/ \
    image my-local-image
```

This issue is also discussed here: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/issues/580